# Combine awk to perform calculation on different columns

Tags: awk

I have the following output below and I want to manipulate the 4th, 7th and 8th column to show in either kilobytes, meagebytes or gigabytes. Column 4 is in bytes and column 7 and 8 is in pages, which is 4 (so multiply the value in column 7 and 8 by 4 to get kilobytes)

```
Segment Summary:
id         key        addr             size             ovhd     class blkused  blkfree
8389645    52564801   700010000000000  686145536        8482408  R     167512   4
3146755    52564802   700020000000000  21474836480      251660232 V     785701   4457179
3146759    52564803   700030000000000  67738288128      1        B     16537668 0
3146756    52564804   700040000000000  43558125568      1        B     10634308 0
3146760    52564805   700050000000000  2195456          27096    M     536      0
3146762    52564806   700060000000000  2195456          27096    M     536      0
3146763    52564807   700070000000000  2195456          27096    M     534      2
4195340    52564808   700080000000000  2195456          27096    M     534      2
Total:     -          -                133466177536     -        -     28127329 4457187

   (* segment locked in memory)
No reserve memory is allocated
```

I have successfully managed to achieve exactly what I want using awk, however I am using three awks instead of one to achieve what I want. See below example command I am using:

```
cat output_file.txt | grep -E '7000|Total:' | awk '{
if ($4 > 1073741824) printf ("%s %s %s %.2f%s %s %s %s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4/1024/1024/1024,"GB",$5,$6,$7,$8;
else if ($4 > 1048576) printf ("%s %s %s %.2f%s %s %s %s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4/1024/1024,"MB",$5,$6,$7,$8;
else if ($4 > 1024) printf ("%s %s %s %.2f%s %s %s %s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4/1024,"KB",$5,$6,$7,$8'} | awk '{
if ($7 > 262144) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,($7*4)/1024/1024,"GB",$8;
else if ($7 > 256) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,($7*4)/1024,"MB",$8;
else if ($7 >= 0) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s %s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7*4,"KB",$8'}       | awk '{
if ($8 > 262144) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,($8*4)/1024/1024,"GB";
else if ($8 > 256) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,($8*4)/1024,"MB";
else if ($8 >= 0) printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %.2f%s\n"),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,"KB"'}
```

The above is a mess. If there is an easier way to achieve what I want, assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Output:

```
8389645 52564801 700010000000000 654.36MB 8482408 R 654.34MB 4.00KB
3146755 52564802 700020000000000 20.00GB 251660232 V 3.00GB 17.00GB
3146759 52564803 700030000000000 63.09GB 1 B 63.09GB 0.00KB
3146756 52564804 700040000000000 40.57GB 1 B 40.57GB 0.00KB
3146760 52564805 700050000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 0.00KB
3146762 52564806 700060000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 0.00KB
3146763 52564807 700070000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 2.00KB
4195340 52564808 700080000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 2.00KB
Total: - - 124.30GB - - 107.30GB 17.00GB
```

Please to demonstate how this can be achieved, you do not have to use my Example output above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea would be to update your fields (`$4`, `$7`, `$8`) when conditionals evaluate to true, then use one consolidated `printf` format to print the line with the (3x) updated field values.

One idea for a rewrite of the current `awk` code:

```
awk '
/7000|Total:/ {      if ($4 > 1073741824) { units[4]="GB"; $4=$4/1024/1024/1024 }
                else if ($4 > 1048576)    { units[4]="MB"; $4=$4/1024/1024      }
                else if ($4 > 1024)       { units[4]="KB"; $4=$4/1024           }

                for (i=7;i<=8;i++) {
                         if ($i >  262144) { units[i]="GB"; $i=($i*4)/1024/1024 }
                    else if ($i >  256)    { units[i]="MB"; $i=($i*4)/1024      }
                    else if ($i >= 0)      { units[i]="KB"; $i=$i               }
                }
                printf "%s %s %s %.2f%s %s %s %.2f%s %.2f%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, units[4], $5, $6, $7, units[7], $8, units[8]
              }
' output_file.txt
```

**NOTE:** this replaces all of OP's current code (`cat | grep | awk | awk | awk`)

This generates:

```
8389645 52564801 700010000000000 654.36MB 8482408 R 654.34MB 4.00KB
3146755 52564802 700020000000000 20.00GB 251660232 V 3.00GB 17.00GB
3146759 52564803 700030000000000 63.09GB 1 B 63.09GB 0.00KB
3146756 52564804 700040000000000 40.57GB 1 B 40.57GB 0.00KB
3146760 52564805 700050000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 0.00KB
3146762 52564806 700060000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 0.00KB
3146763 52564807 700070000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 2.00KB
4195340 52564808 700080000000000 2.09MB 27096 M 2.09MB 2.00KB
Total: - - 124.30GB - - 107.30GB 17.00GB
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the calculation part. you can fill in the units manually :

```
echo '

Segment Summary:
id         key        addr             size             ovhd     class blkused  blkfree
8389645    52564801   700010000000000  686145536        8482408  R     167512   4
3146755    52564802   700020000000000  21474836480      251660232 V     785701   4457179
3146759    52564803   700030000000000  67738288128      1        B     16537668 0
3146756    52564804   700040000000000  43558125568      1        B     10634308 0
3146760    52564805   700050000000000  2195456          27096    M     536      0
3146762    52564806   700060000000000  2195456          27096    M     536      0
3146763    52564807   700070000000000  2195456          27096    M     534      2
4195340    52564808   700080000000000  2195456          27096    M     534      2
Total:     -          -                133466177536     -        -     28127329 4457187' |
```

> ```
>   mawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = OFMT = "%.7f" 
>                      _ +=_+=_^ = _<_ 
>         } (__ = +$_) { 
>             if ((___= _++^_--)<__) { 
>                 $_ /= ___^ ( (_^(--_*_)<__) + \
>                      ((_++-+-++_)^(_+_)<__) + !!--_) 
>             }
>             for(___ = _+_-!!_; ___ <= NF; ___++) { 
>             
>                $___ *= (_^-(_+_+(-_)^((\
>                  __  = +$___)<_^(--_*_++))))^(_^_<__) 
>             } 
>         } _'
> ```

```
Segment  Summary:
id       key       addr             size         ovhd       class  blkused      blkfree
8389645  52564801  700010000000000  654.3593750  8482408    R      654.3437500  4
3146755  52564802  700020000000000  20           251660232  V      2.9972115    17.0027885
3146759  52564803  700030000000000  63.0861969   1          B      63.0861969   0
3146756  52564804  700040000000000  40.5666656   1          B      40.5666656   0
3146760  52564805  700050000000000  2.0937500    27096      M      2.0937500    0
3146762  52564806  700060000000000  2.0937500    27096      M      2.0937500    0
3146763  52564807  700070000000000  2.0937500    27096      M      2.0859375    2
4195340  52564808  700080000000000  2.0937500    27096      M      2.0859375    2
Total:   -         -                124.3000641  -          -      107.2972450  17.0028191
```